# i can't install any packages because of Composer memory limit error

Tags: api, composer-php, symfony-2.8

i am new to symfony and i am working on a project of symfony 2.8, i have to build a RESTful api for the app, but everytime i want to install a new package by composer i face this error below.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar://C:/composer/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php on line 129

i tried all the answers on the net with no results..please help me i have a deadline on this project!!

Comment: The linked question provides answers that should help in your case as well. You can either use `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require ...` or use `php -d memory_limit=-1 C:\Users\...\composer require ...` (important you have to specify the full path to your composer executable in the second example).

Comment: Thank you @dbrumann..this one "php -d memory_limit=-1 C:\Users\...\composer require ..." worked for me.